# How do I show the date field from an Object on Visualforce component in MM.DD.YYYY format instead of MM/DD/YYYY?

Tags: apex, community

I have an ODate__c field on one of the Object. But I try to show on component it shows as MM/DD/YYYY but I want it to be displayed as MM.DD.YYYY. Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? And what are you stuck on?

Comment: Could you post your sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000Xda9QAC) (use it as a reference)

Example(taken from the above link):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd' 'MMMMM' 'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!yourDate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

You may need to adjust the date format according to your requirement.

Comment: Can you please add more information for the link you shared? In the event of link gets broken in the future this answer won't be helpful to anyone without the information.

Comment: @tugce, I don't think the above-mentioned link can be removed/broken, but still, I have modified my answer as you suggested.